# Store Image in DataTable, Show in GridView, Eventually Store in DB

Tags: c#, image-processing, binary

I have the need to allow the user to upload files to a server. These are image files and before they are stored in the database, I need the user to supply additional about the image they are uploading.

So far I have a HTML 5 multi file upload:

```
<asp:FileUpload ID="fuTestUpload" AllowMultiple="true" runat="server" />
```

I am displaying the file name and a drop down list where the user can select what the category of the image being uploaded is:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvHierarchy" AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnRowDataBound="gvHierarchy_RowDataBound" runat="server">
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Choose Files">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:CheckBox Id="chkBox" runat="server"/>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>

            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Assigned Location">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddl" Width="150" runat="server">
                        <asp:ListItem Text="-- select --" Value="0"></asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>

            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="File Path">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label Id="lblFilePath"  runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("FilePath")%>'/>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>          

            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Location Image">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Image Id="imgLocation" runat="server" Width="200" ImageUrl='<%#Eval("ImageData")%>'/>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

I am populating the image back to the grid view here:

```
protected void btnUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (fuTestUpload.HasFiles)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Clear();
        dt.Columns.Add("FilePath");
        dt.Columns.Add("ImageData");

        foreach (HttpPostedFile file in fuTestUpload.PostedFiles)
        {
            DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
            dr["FilePath"] = file.FileName.ToString();
            Byte[] bImage = new Byte[file.ContentLength];
            Stream myStream = file.InputStream;
            myStream.Read(bImage, 0, file.ContentLength);
            dr["ImageData"] = myStream;
            dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        }

        Session["UploadedImageData"] = dt;
        populateGrid(dt);
    }
}
```

However this is not working, it is either blank or various byte/stream errors.

Any idea how to achieve this?

**Solved with this**

```
if (fuTestUpload.HasFiles)
    {            
        foreach (HttpPostedFile file in fuTestUpload.PostedFiles)
        {
            byte[] bImage = new byte[file.ContentLength];
            file.InputStream.Read(bImage, 0, file.ContentLength);

            success = myClass.TempStoreLocationImages(bImage, file.FileName.ToString());                
        }      
    }
```

Appreciate suggestions regarding bounty award v answer as I'm not sure.

Comment: Should the btnUpload_Click code be like this instead: `dr["ImageData"] = bImage;` ?

Comment: I tried both Simon, with no success - however there's an inherent difficulty with verifying binary data as correct!

Answer (score 0):

"Blank" errors of byte/stream errors kind of makes me think the problem is further up the chain. Is the upload in an Ajax container? Can you stick a breakpoint at the first line in the Upload method invocation, and hit that breakpoint? If the answer is no, open up an Http debugger like Fiddler and confirm the traffic is coming to your debug server correctly.

Comment: The upload is in the code above which is the ASP.NET upload control, however I am now looking more towards this control and how you get data from the upload control and convert it to binary data for storing.

Answer (score 0):

The column type in the data table is wrong.

This means that you are storing the string representation of a byte[] (the `System.Byte[]` string).

Use:

```
 dt.Columns.Add("ImageData", typeof(byte[]));
```